# If the .osm file encodes all geospatial data, or if Mapnik encodes part of it too

Tags: openstreetmap, vector, rendering

I have downloaded the whole OpenStreetMap .osm file, and not wanting to decompress it or try to open it in a text editor (at almost a terabyte in size), I am looking at [this XML](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/OSM_XML) as an example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<osm version="0.6" generator="CGImap 0.0.2">
 <bounds minlat="54.0889580" minlon="12.2487570" maxlat="54.0913900" maxlon="12.2524800"/>
 <node id="298884269" lat="54.0901746" lon="12.2482632" user="SvenHRO" uid="46882" visible="true" version="1" changeset="676636" timestamp="2008-09-21T21:37:45Z"/>
 <node id="261728686" lat="54.0906309" lon="12.2441924" user="PikoWinter" uid="36744" visible="true" version="1" changeset="323878" timestamp="2008-05-03T13:39:23Z"/>
 <node id="1831881213" version="1" changeset="12370172" lat="54.0900666" lon="12.2539381" user="lafkor" uid="75625" visible="true" timestamp="2012-07-20T09:43:19Z">
  <tag k="name" v="Neu Broderstorf"/>
  <tag k="traffic_sign" v="city_limit"/>
 </node>
 ...
 <node id="298884272" lat="54.0901447" lon="12.2516513" user="SvenHRO" uid="46882" visible="true" version="1" changeset="676636" timestamp="2008-09-21T21:37:45Z"/>
 <way id="26659127" user="Masch" uid="55988" visible="true" version="5" changeset="4142606" timestamp="2010-03-16T11:47:08Z">
  <nd ref="292403538"/>
  <nd ref="298884289"/>
  ...
  <nd ref="261728686"/>
  <tag k="highway" v="unclassified"/>
  <tag k="name" v="Pastower Straße"/>
 </way>
 <relation id="56688" user="kmvar" uid="56190" visible="true" version="28" changeset="6947637" timestamp="2011-01-12T14:23:49Z">
  <member type="node" ref="294942404" role=""/>
  ...
  <member type="node" ref="364933006" role=""/>
  <member type="way" ref="4579143" role=""/>
  ...
  <member type="node" ref="249673494" role=""/>
  <tag k="name" v="Küstenbus Linie 123"/>
  <tag k="network" v="VVW"/>
  <tag k="operator" v="Regionalverkehr Küste"/>
  <tag k="ref" v="123"/>
  <tag k="route" v="bus"/>
  <tag k="type" v="route"/>
 </relation>
 ...
</osm>
```

It looks like there are 3 objects: node, way, and relation, and they have some other basic structure. What I don't see here is the actual sort of "vector graphics" stuff, and shapefile sort of stuff (though I am not familiar with shapefiles either yet). I would expect to see polygons and colors and such, but it just looks like lat/long coordinates and some chains of them ("ways"), and names of some landmarks and such.

Wondering what I do as the next step (staying at the lowest level, that is, not using a map editor or program to view the file which handles a bunch of stuff magically). I would like to know how to go from here, to rendering it on screen. If it is involved, just the gist of where I need to go next.

The wiki was down for a while, but now it's back up and the [Elements page](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Elements) suggests the "ways" might define the area boundaries like lakes and rivers and such, so that's good. But I don't see yet how to go from here to the concept of tile rendering. I would like to implement tile rendering so not using a prebuilt tile server.

[This](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Mapnik/Rendering_OSM_XML_data_directly) seems like it is similar to what I am asking about. It looks like [Mapnik](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Mapnik_Example) is used to do the rendering, but I am not sure if it has its own set of geospatial data for encoding polygons and such, or if that is entirely encapsulated in OSM (would be helpful if that were clarified for me). If OSM encodes all the data for the geospatial stuff, then that means Mapnik is purely the colors and the layout of text and other non-geospatial stuff. That would make more sense.

Comment: Your last assumption is true: Mapnik is only a rendering software (and not the only one that can use OSM data).

Comment: I wish you good luck opening a 1TB XML document in a text editor..., but rather advice you to have a good look at these good sources about OpenStreetMap and its technical background: 1) The "Switch to OSM" website: https://switch2osm.org/  2) The "Component Overview" of the OpenStreetMap Wiki: https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Component_overview. This should give you at least a basic idea of what is going on under the hood of OpenStreetMap, even though some or many of the components may as of yet be unfamiliar to you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The basic OSM data model (nodes, ways and relations) is described at [Elements](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Elements). The XML format is described at [OSM XML](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/OSM_XML), larger extracts usually use [PBF](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/PBF_Format) instead of XML, PBF has performance advantages (size, speed).

OSM is mainly a geographic database. It doesn't contain "colors" (well, there are a few exceptions like the color of a particular building). Colors are part of the map rendering. However the [rendering](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Rendering) is done by data consumers, i..e this is a post-processing step. There are many different renderers available, each one with their own stylesheet. OSM (usually) doesn't tell you how the color of a particular geographic object looks like, it just tells you the shape. The rendering stylesheet defines which color a forest and which color a farmland has. This is not part of the geographic database because it is not really a geographic fact.

Mapnik is just one of many different renderers. If you render a map with Mapnik then all the geographic data has to come from an external source (for example from OSM) while all the "how should this particular thing look like" comes from a stylesheet.